# Randomize w/no repeats using R

Tags: r, repeat

How can randomize the following matrix without repetition of the numbers using R??

```
g=sample(1:28, 28), replace=T)
HW=matrix(g, ncol=4, byrow=T)
HW=as.table(HW)
HW
```

Comment: It's much better to use TRUE/FALSE than T/F in your code

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're currently sampling with replacement.  Turning it off should give you the behavior you want:

```
g = sample(1:28, 28, replace=F)
```

Comment: And since the default value of `replace` is `TRUE`, you could simply do `sample(1:28, 28)` with no `replace` param at all.

Comment: Even more compact would be:  `sample(1:28)` This is also called a "permutation".